Accessing parent div from child element
I have 2 radio buttons. Each of these radio buttons are connected to an image.
At the start these images are in black and white (filter:grayscale(1)).
When one of these buttons are selected, I want the image the button relates to turn (filter:grayscale(0)).
The grayscale filter attribute is specified in the <img> element. Each of these radio buttons are wrapped into a seperate div, with their respective <img>.
The first step (I think) is to collect the input name that relates to the radio button that is selected. And this works.
I believe from this input name, I need to search for the parent div, and then look for the <img> element it relates to.
I will admit it, writing this feels a bit complicated. But I cannot think of a better way.
my problem
Where I am struggling now is to fetch the parent div based on the checked input name.
I found a bit of document using either .parentElement(), .parent() and parent.Node() but none of these work. Or probably I am not using them properly.
Then once the parent div is identified, I can probably look for the child <img> element.
My question(s)

How do I access the parent div from the child element id?
Is there a better way/ simpler way to achieve this?



$(document).ready(function() {
  /*Manages Radio buttons & images rendering when clicked*/
  $('input[name="hero-avatar"]').change(function() {
    // Check if the radio button is checked
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // captures id of button that is checked
      let checkButton = $(this).attr('id');
      // Log checked radio button id
      console.log(checkButton);

      //test to find parent div class
      console.log($(`#${checkButton}`).parent().attr('class'));

      //this works but doesnt reach the parent div class which contains grayscale property
      $(`#${checkButton}`.parentNode).css('filter', 'grayscale(0)')

    }
  });

  //if radio button is checked
  //change colour of image attached to it
});
.avatar-img-select {
  height: 52px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row first-screen-row-avatar">
  <div class="col select-avatar-col">
    <label for="avatar1">
        <img src="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-1.jpg" class="avatar-img-select" alt="Avatar 1">
        <input type="radio" id="avatar1" name="hero-avatar" value="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-1.jpg" required>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col select-avatar-col">
    <label for="avatar2">
        <img src="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-2.webp" class="avatar-img-select" alt="Avatar 2">
        <input type="radio" id="avatar2" name="hero-avatar" value="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-2.webp" required>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>




Try the following instead? $(\#${checkButton}`).parent().css('filter','grayscale(0)')checkButton is a string soparentNodewould beundefined`.

you should be able to use $(\#${checkButton}`).parentElement.css('filter','grayscale(0)'). the reason parentElementwasn't working in your code is because it's not a function, it's just part of theElement` Object.

@Isaakfire You're mixing jQuery and DOM.

I generally recommend using .closest() rather than parent relationships. That way it doesn't break if you insert wrappers that may be needed for styling.

the console displays this: S.fn.init {0: label, length: 1, prevObject: S.fn.init} if I console.log(console.log($(#${checkButton}).parent().css('filter','grayscale(0)'));). I did come across this earlier, but I wasnt too sure what this meant. Clicking on the arrow now I realise I can see a list of attributes including first child element which has the class I am looking to reach.

@Isaakfire Also, if you're writing a code snippet that contains backticks, wrap it with triple-backticks.

You might consider editing your question and removing that second question because it's off topic. Both "better" and "simpler" are subject, and opinionated questions are off topic.  Also, asking more than one question is off topic (lacks focus).

@Barmar The solution I have definitely works in the DOM, I don't usually use jQuery. thanks for the correction on formatting though. EDIT: I just realized that this post is on jQuery, I somehow completely missed the formatting and I just assumed it was the DOM, so yeah, you're right, sorry.

@Isaakfire Right, it works for the dom, but $(...) doesn't return a DOM element, it returns a jQuery collection. The equivalent is .parent() as i AngYC's comment.

You can do this entirely without jQuery or JavaScript and a CSS one-liner using :has():
label:has(input:checked) img {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}



label:has(input:checked) img {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
.avatar-img-select {
  height: 52px;
  filter: grayscale(1);
}
<div class="row first-screen-row-avatar">
  <div class="col select-avatar-col">
    <label for="avatar1">
        <img src="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-1.jpg" class="avatar-img-select" alt="Avatar 1">
        <input type="radio" id="avatar1" name="hero-avatar" value="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-1.jpg" required>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col select-avatar-col">
    <label for="avatar2">
        <img src="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-2.webp" class="avatar-img-select" alt="Avatar 2">
        <input type="radio" id="avatar2" name="hero-avatar" value="assets/images/avatars/hero-avatar-2.webp" required>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks! there was indeed a very simple answer to that. Thank you also for the comment about using $(#${checkButton}).parent().css('filter','grayscale(0)'). I started learning javascript. This forced me to question what I was seeing and found some interesting stuff I can probably use later.
